# How do you center N*M matrix in Python using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a N by M array where N corresponds to the number of points in an M dimensional space. I would like to center these points by subtracting the mean point using the learn library.

Comment: Do you mean normalization or what you really need is normalization?

Comment: if you need preprocess the data try [`sklearn.preprocessing`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing)

Answer (score 4):

you don't need sklearn for this, you'll use `numpy` (which is also used by scikit-learn). Here is an example for N = 2 and M = 3:

```
import numpy as np
points = np.array([
   [1.,2.,3.],   # 1st point
   [4.,5.,6.]]   # 2nd point
)

meanPoint = points.mean(axis = 0)

# subtract mean point
points -= meanPoint
```